# unable to specify value in ActiveRecord call (Ruby, Sinatra, not Rails)

Tags: ruby, activerecord, sinatra, sinatra-activerecord

I have a reference to a Model object called Admin which has a field called id.  The object property is accessible in the puts line.  I now need to pass in that ID into an ActiveRecord call to create another object (where it serves as foreign key) as follows but it throws an exception copied below (the admin.id does not get picked up in the Bill.create call):

```
admin = Admin.find_by(email:email)
puts "admin id #{admin.id}"  # this gets printed with correct value  
bill = Bill.create(admin_id: admin.id, body: body)
```

**Exception**:

```
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:59:in `rescue in _assign_attribute': unknown attribute 'admin_id' for Bill. (ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError)
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:54:in `_assign_attribute'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:41:in `block in assign_attributes'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:35:in `each'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:35:in `assign_attributes'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/core.rb:564:in `init_attributes'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/core.rb:281:in `initialize'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:61:in `new'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:61:in `new'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:33:in `create'
        from test.rb:34:in `<main>'
```

**ActiveRecord migration for the Bills model**:

```
 def up
     create_table :bills do |t|
         t.integer :admin_id
         t.text :body
     end
    add_foreign_key :bills, :admins
  end
```

Thank you in advance for sharing insights on what I am doing wrong.

Comment: The error has to do with `admin_id` not existing in your `Bills` model, not about `admin.id` from the Admin object. Check your migration.

Comment: Instead of fixing the problem immediately, you should really restructure this to use a belongs_to association... http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-belongs-to-association

Answer (score 0):

Per my comment, you should really make this into a `belongs_to` relation, here's the refactored migration (using latest Rails 4 syntax):

```
class CreateBills < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :bills do |t|
      t.references :admin
      t.text :body
    end
  end
end
```

add these relations to the models:

```
class Admin < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bills
end

class Bill < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :admin
end
```

and the code for creating a bill associated with an admin:

```
admin = Admin.find_by(email:email)
puts "admin id #{admin.id}"  # this gets printed with correct value  
bill = admin.bills.create(body: body)
```